# Position Label on top of text-area

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I want to place label on top of an html area in the format shown in this picture.I am using vertical align property but the label is coming on the left hand side of the text-area

[image: The desired format]

The current format i am getting is like this http://jsfiddle.net/aMLFE/

the css code being used is

```
textarea { vertical-align: top; }
```

Please tell me how to position label in the format given in the image..

Comment: Try the posted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Demo

CSS:

```
label {display:block;}
textarea { display:block;}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="title">Title: </label>
<textarea rows="5" id="title" name="title"></textarea>
```

There are so many ways to achieve what you need, but for the snippet that you have provided this is sufficient.

Comment: Great solution -- I don't know why I never thought of it before.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :-

```
<label for="title">Title : </label>
<br/>
<textarea rows="5" id="title" name="title"></textarea>
```

Run [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMLFE/23/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Tag Called **Fieldset** For your requirement.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Lable</legend>
  Data in the Box comes Here...!!
 </fieldset>
```

Hope this is what you want..!!

Here is the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/hZLhv/

Comment: Wow, thank you @Sree ram. This is amazing, how did I not know about this for so long!

Answer (score 1):

The semantic approach is by using DL and DT.

```
<form>
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="title">Title : </label></dt>
        <dt><textarea rows="5" id="title" name="title"></textarea></dt>
    </dl>
</form>

FORM DL {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Is this correct? A form can be clasified as "definition list"?

Comment: Its a design choice. But the important point is having block level elements surrounding the inline.